# Automata|f(L) take the length of a regular language's prefix to the length of the rest

Tags: automata

If $f$ is a function of integers, define $f(L)$ to be 
$$
\{w \mid \text{for some $x$, with $|x| = f(|w|)$, we have $wx$ in $L$}\}.
$$

Show that if $L$ is a regular language, then so if $f(L)$, if $f$ is one of the following functions:

1. $f(n)=n^2$ (i.e., the amount we take has length equal to the square root of what we do not take)
2. $f(n)=2^n$

This is a question from John Hopcroft's Introduction to Automata Theory, that is, Exercise 4.2.9.
And I find it hard to construct a automata like what we do in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539658/automata-prove-that-if-l-is-regular-than-halfl-is-regular-too).